# Cygwin compilation error Problematic frame: # C [cygwin1.dll+0xd6d47] using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, cygwin, native

I've made a simple hello world application using JNI everything works good even the dll for my 64 bit gets created but when i run the app it shows the following error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180116d47, pid=2140, tid=0x0000000000001710
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xd6d47]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Here is the complete error report :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180116d47, pid=2140, tid=0x0000000000001710
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xd6d47]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002bd0800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5904, stack(0x0000000002a10000,0x0000000002b10000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000000000070

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000070, RBX=0x0000000017270278, RCX=0x00000004344a3030, RDX=0x0000000002b0f4f8
RSP=0x0000000002b0f430, RBP=0x0000000002b0f460, RSI=0x0000000020000021, RDI=0x00000000ffffffff
R8 =0x0000000000000004, R9 =0x0000000001217f70, R10=0x0000000002b10000, R11=0x00000004344a10ac
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000017270278, R14=0x0000000002b0f4f8, R15=0x0000000002bd0800
RIP=0x0000000180116d47, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000002b0f430)
0x0000000002b0f430:   000000018018c780 0000000180116d5b
0x0000000002b0f440:   0000000002b0f700 0000000002bd0800
0x0000000002b0f450:   0000000017270278 0000000020000021
0x0000000002b0f460:   0000000002b0f4d8 0000000002ce7f74
0x0000000002b0f470:   0000000002bd09f8 0000000002b0f4f8
0x0000000002b0f480:   0000000020000021 0000000002bd0800
0x0000000002b0f490:   0000000002ce7ca2 0000000002b0f498
0x0000000002b0f4a0:   0000000017270278 0000000002b0f4f8
0x0000000002b0f4b0:   0000000017270410 0000000000000000
0x0000000002b0f4c0:   0000000017270278 0000000000000000
0x0000000002b0f4d0:   0000000002b0f4f8 0000000002b0f540
0x0000000002b0f4e0:   0000000002cd835d 0000000000000000
0x0000000002b0f4f0:   0000000002ce19d8 00000000d5e6e2f0
0x0000000002b0f500:   0000000002b0f500 0000000017270317
0x0000000002b0f510:   0000000002b0f550 0000000017270410
0x0000000002b0f520:   0000000000000000 0000000017270320 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000180116d47)
0x0000000180116d27:   04 f3 90 eb e3 48 c7 c0 08 00 00 00 49 0f c1 82
0x0000000180116d37:   50 e4 ff ff 4c 8d 1d 19 00 00 00 4c 87 5c 24 08
0x0000000180116d47:   4c 89 18 41 ff 82 44 e4 ff ff 41 ff 8a 4c e4 ff
0x0000000180116d57:   ff 58 ff e0 65 4c 8b 14 25 08 00 00 00 41 bb 01 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000070 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x0000000017270280} 'print' '()V' in 'javatoc'
RCX=0x00000004344a3030 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000002b0f4f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002bd0800
RSP=0x0000000002b0f430 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002bd0800
RBP=0x0000000002b0f460 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002bd0800
RSI=0x0000000020000021 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000ffffffff is an unallocated location in the heap
R8 =0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000001217f70 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000002b10000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002bd0800
R11=0x00000004344a10ac is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x0000000017270280} 'print' '()V' in 'javatoc'
R14=0x0000000002b0f4f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002bd0800
R15=0x0000000002bd0800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000002a10000,0x0000000002b10000],  sp=0x0000000002b0f430,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [cygwin1.dll+0xd6d47]
C  [cygwin1.dll+0x14c77f]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  javatoc.print()V+0
j  javatoc.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000019428800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1096, stack(0x0000000019800000,0x0000000019900000)]
  0x000000001781f000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4500, stack(0x0000000019300000,0x0000000019400000)]
  0x000000001781a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5164, stack(0x0000000019200000,0x0000000019300000)]
  0x0000000017816800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3924, stack(0x0000000019100000,0x0000000019200000)]
  0x0000000017815000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1188, stack(0x0000000019000000,0x0000000019100000)]
  0x0000000017812000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3188, stack(0x0000000018f00000,0x0000000019000000)]
  0x0000000002cca800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3732, stack(0x0000000018a60000,0x0000000018b60000)]
  0x0000000002cbf800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=192, stack(0x0000000018960000,0x0000000018a60000)]
=>0x0000000002bd0800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5904, stack(0x0000000002a10000,0x0000000002b10000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000177d8000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000018860000,0x0000000018960000] [id=5348]
  0x0000000019452800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000019900000,0x0000000019a00000] [id=5728]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 1331K [0x00000000d5e00000, 0x00000000d8880000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 4% used [0x00000000d5e00000,0x00000000d5f4cce8,0x00000000d7e80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8380000,0x00000000d8880000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d7e80000,0x00000000d8380000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081a00000, 0x0000000086f80000, 0x00000000d5e00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081a00000,0x0000000081a00000,0x0000000086f80000)
 Metaspace       used 2598K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 283K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012090000,0x0000000012490000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011c83000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000060a0c720
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012b40000, 0x0000000014ad8000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014ad8000, 0x0000000016a70000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001040000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1106Kb max_used=1115Kb free=244653Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002cd0000, 0x0000000002f40000, 0x0000000011cd0000]
 total_blobs=257 nmethods=26 adapters=145
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.059 Thread 0x000000001781f000   21       3       java.io.WinNTFileSystem::isSlash (18 bytes)
Event: 0.059 Thread 0x000000001781f000 nmethod 21 0x0000000002de2910 code [0x0000000002de2a60, 0x0000000002de2c50]
Event: 0.059 Thread 0x000000001781f000   23       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (50 bytes)
Event: 0.059 Thread 0x000000001781a000   24       4       java.lang.String::charAt (29 bytes)
Event: 0.060 Thread 0x000000001781f000 nmethod 23 0x0000000002de2cd0 code [0x0000000002de2ea0, 0x0000000002de35f8]
Event: 0.060 Thread 0x000000001781f000   25       3       java.lang.String::indexOf (7 bytes)
Event: 0.060 Thread 0x000000001781f000 nmethod 25 0x0000000002de3910 code [0x0000000002de3a80, 0x0000000002de3c88]
Event: 0.060 Thread 0x000000001781a000 nmethod 24 0x0000000002de69d0 code [0x0000000002de6b20, 0x0000000002de6bd8]
Event: 0.063 Thread 0x000000001781f000   26       3       java.lang.StringBuilder::append (8 bytes)
Event: 0.063 Thread 0x000000001781f000 nmethod 26 0x0000000002de5e50 code [0x0000000002de5fc0, 0x0000000002de6148]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.023 Thread 0x0000000002bd0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5e07ca8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\
Event: 0.023 Thread 0x0000000002bd0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5e07f90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.063 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection
Event: 0.063 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection done
Event: 0.063 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper
Event: 0.063 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper done
Event: 0.063 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray
Event: 0.063 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray done
Event: 0.064 loading class java/lang/Void
Event: 0.064 loading class java/lang/Void done
Event: 0.064 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper
Event: 0.064 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff690580000 - 0x00007ff6905b7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffc37930000 - 0x00007ffc37ada000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffc37230000 - 0x00007ffc3736a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffc350a0000 - 0x00007ffc351af000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffc33620000 - 0x00007ffc336a8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffc1cea0000 - 0x00007ffc1ceef000     C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ffc35280000 - 0x00007ffc35327000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffc34a70000 - 0x00007ffc34a9b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffc376c0000 - 0x00007ffc37711000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffc37540000 - 0x00007ffc376b1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffc35a90000 - 0x00007ffc35c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffc35e10000 - 0x00007ffc37227000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffc342b0000 - 0x00007ffc342ce000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffc351b0000 - 0x00007ffc35255000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffc2f320000 - 0x00007ffc2f33b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffc35760000 - 0x00007ffc35896000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffc35db0000 - 0x00007ffc35e07000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffc35520000 - 0x00007ffc356f6000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ffc37370000 - 0x00007ffc374b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffc34ca0000 - 0x00007ffc34cb4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffc33140000 - 0x00007ffc331df000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffc378e0000 - 0x00007ffc37914000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffc35950000 - 0x00007ffc35a89000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffc32350000 - 0x00007ffc325aa000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17031_none_6242a4b3ecbb55a1\COMCTL32.dll
0x0000000060a90000 - 0x0000000060b62000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000601f0000 - 0x0000000060a8c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffc32070000 - 0x00007ffc32079000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffc22da0000 - 0x00007ffc22dbf000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffc2e7c0000 - 0x00007ffc2e7ca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffc374d0000 - 0x00007ffc374d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffc35700000 - 0x00007ffc35758000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffc22d70000 - 0x00007ffc22d9a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffc35330000 - 0x00007ffc35339000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffc34d70000 - 0x00007ffc34dba000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffc33b30000 - 0x00007ffc33b56000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00000000601e0000 - 0x00000000601ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000601b0000 - 0x00000000601d9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000060190000 - 0x00000000601a6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00000004344a0000 - 0x00000004344b8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javatoc.dll
0x0000000180040000 - 0x0000000180610000     C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
0x00007ffc0b5a0000 - 0x00007ffc0b728000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: javatoc
java_class_path (initial): .
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\swigwin-3.0.12;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\win32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include;;C:\Python27;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\bin
USERNAME=User
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17056)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8279416k(5777792k free), swap 9655672k(6364908k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sat May 20 16:25:17 2017
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I'm using CYGWIN 64 bit version, but unable to get what the exact error is.
Following is the javatoc.java file code

```
import java.io.*;
public class javatoc
{
    public native void print();

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("javatoc");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new javatoc().print();
    }
}
```

Here is the javatoc.c file code

```
#include "jni.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_javatoc_print
  (JNIEnv *evn, jobject obj)
  {
    printf("Hello World");
  }
```

Commands used for execution :

```
javac javatoc.java

javah -jni javatoc

gcc -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/win32" -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -shared javatoc.c -o javatoc.dll
```

Can anyone please help me out with this and let me know what this error is about.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get JNI to work with Cygwin's `g++` -- that induces a dependency on cygwin1.dll, which clashes with the JNI mechanism, causing a crash. But using `/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` fixed the problem for me.